# add image into input tag

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make a search bar using an input and to add to it a svg.
this is how it should look like

[image]

this is my code

```css
.search-input-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit" class="search-input-btn"><img src="assets/images/search-input-btn.svg"></button>
</div>
```

and this is how it looks like so far

[image]

Comment: remove paddings(padding: 18px 20px) from your .search-input-btn css class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform property to align it vertically.

```
.search-input-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  z-index: 2;
transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```